# How to delete item from CollectionView with SwipeView in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, collectionview, swipeview

I am currently making a note-taking app. I am new so excuse my lack of knowledge.
I am using the default flyout menu template given with changes made to cater for my needs. I am using a SwipeView in my CollectionView so when you swipe on a 'note' the item will delete on execute.

I have the swipe working but I cannot get the item to delete once swiped.

This is my ItemsPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="xamarinMobileTest.Views.ItemsPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xamarinMobileTest.ViewModels"  
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:xamarinMobileTest.Models"  
             x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Add Note" Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:ItemsViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <RefreshView x:DataType="local:ItemsViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                SelectionMode="None">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                     <SwipeView>
                        <SwipeView.RightItems>
                            <SwipeItems Mode="Execute">
                                <SwipeItem Text="Delete" 
                                           BackgroundColor="Red"
                                           Command="{Binding DeleteItemCommand}"
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </SwipeItems>
                        </SwipeView.RightItems>
                        <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:Item">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Text}"
                                   LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                                   Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                                   FontSize="16"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   TextColor="Black"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" 
                                   LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                   Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                                   FontSize="13"
                                   TextColor="Black"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding DueDate}"
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                                   FontSize="13"
                                   TextColor="Black"/>
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ItemsViewModel}}, Path=ItemTapped}"     
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                                </TapGestureRecognizer>
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                       </StackLayout>
                    </SwipeView>
                </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
    </RefreshView>
</ContentPage>
```

ItemsViewModel:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    
    using xamarinMobileTest.Models;
    using xamarinMobileTest.Views;

    namespace xamarinMobileTest.ViewModels
    {
    public class ItemsViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private Item _selectedItem;

        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }
        public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; }
        public Command AddItemCommand { get; }
        public Command<Item> ItemTapped { get; }

        public Command<Item> DeleteItemCommand { get; }

        public ItemsViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Notes";
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());

            ItemTapped = new Command<Item>(OnItemSelected);

            AddItemCommand = new Command(OnAddItem);

            DeleteItemCommand = new Command<Item>(OnDeleteItem);
    }

        async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            try
            {
                Items.Clear();
                var items = await DataStore.GetItemsAsync(true);
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }

        public void OnAppearing()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            SelectedItem = null;
        }

        public Item SelectedItem
        {
            get => _selectedItem;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
                OnItemSelected(value);
            }
        }

        private async void OnAddItem(object obj)
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(NewItemPage));
        }

        async void OnItemSelected(Item item)
        {
            if (item == null)
                return;

            // This will push the ItemDetailPage onto the navigation stack
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ItemDetailPage)}?{nameof(ItemDetailViewModel.ItemId)}={item.Id}");
        }

        private void OnDeleteItem(Item item)
        {
            Items.Remove(item);
        }

    }
}
```

*Other code needed can be found by opening up default flyout menu template

How do I delete an Item on a swipe in the observable collection so that when I delete the Item it automatically is seen that the item is deleted?

`Items.Remove(item);` does not seem to work (no error, just does not remove the item from the CollectionView) Why is this?

`await DataStore.DeleteItemAsync(item);` has the same issue of nothing happening when the item is swiped.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Generally speaking, you need to remove one (like `await DataStore.DelItemAsync(item);`) from the DataStore and execute Load method again. And seems you also need a command parameter for the command.

Comment: I tried to create a Command DeleteItemCommand and OnDeleteItem method like in your code. When I run DeleteItemCommand = new Command(OnDeleteItem); there is no compile error. I tried to use items. Remove and no error was reported. You could upload a basic, minimal, reproducible project to github and attach the link here. Then I will download and test it.

Comment: here is my github upload: https://github.com/Zystryx/Note-Taking-App

Comment: You need to delete the parameters of the OnDeleteItem method. You can get the data outside the method and use it inside the method. I suggest you use the Invoked method, so you can get the information directly inside the method and perform the delete operation, which is easier.

Comment: so in the swipeitem, use Invoked instead of Command? then in OnInvokedMethod to get the data and delete the item? @WenxuLi

Comment: Yes, this document can help you(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/swipeview)

Comment: @WenxuLi hey, I have read through this recently and had read it again today, I just can't seem to work out how to retrieve the selected Item and am then unsure on how to execute and delete the item? Are you able to possibly make a mock-up example of doing so and then I can apply it to my own use? This would be useful thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your parameter to this

```
 CommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=BindingContext}"
```

Comment: THIS!  You rock.  I've been stuck on this issue for hours. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

the code you have in `OnDeleteItem` is nonsensical.  It should look something like this

```
private void OnDeleteItem(Item item)
{
    Items.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this code but when I add it, I get the compile error "Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action<object>' where Command = new Command(OnDeleteItem)                             How do I fix this?

Comment: if you are passing a parameter you need to use `Command<T>`

Comment: This fixed my error thanks - However, the code still does not delete the item. Once the item is swiped nothing happens. Is this because it is not getting the item from the collectionView? Or am I seeing no change because the collectionView has not yet been updated?

Answer (score 0):

Trying same thing with Tabbed page from default project.
Noticed that Command is not running at all not matter what I do. (using Debug)

```
   Try putting delete button in ItemDetailPage.
   In ItemDetailPageViewModel put this code.

        public Command DeleteCommand { get; set; }

             public ItemDetailViewModel()
             {
                 DeleteCommand = new Command(OnDelete);
              }

                 private async void OnDelete()
                  {
                    await DataStore.DeleteItemAsync(Id);
                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
                   }



                       with ItemDetailPageViewModel you have the Id to delete 

              ItemDetailPage code here

                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
                      <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                      
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinDeleteItem.ViewModels"
         x:Class="XamarinDeleteItem.Views.ItemDetailPage"
         Title="{Binding Title}">

             <ContentPage.BindingContext>
                  <local:ItemDetailViewModel />
             </ContentPage.BindingContext>

<StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15">
    <Label Text="Text:" FontSize="Medium" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="Small"/>
    <Label Text="Description:" FontSize="Medium" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="Small"/>
    <Button Text="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is SwipeView even supported by Command?

Goto page 221 in this PDF
found this in Xamarin.Forms Documentation. download here

https://opdhsblobprod03.blob.core.windows.net/contents/332e36c8b2484d748610a3dd6b6e98d6/190868cccec033e90406d3cafdb40d3d?skoid=29100048-1fa1-4ada-b0e0-e2aa294fc66a&sktid=975f013f-7f24-47e8-a7d3-abc4752bf346&skt=2022-09-18T13%3A52%3A55Z&ske=2022-09-25T13%3A57%3A55Z&sks=b&skv=2020-10-02&sv=2020-08-04&se=2022-09-20T23%3A36%3A35Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=0myHYJIb3aEzMUIuCtmXn4VN%2F0MC8gzG1k7%2BQCMZVno%3D

```
To allow ViewModels to be moreindependent of particular user interface objects but still allow methods to be
```

called within the ViewModel,a command interfaceexists.This command interface is supported by the following
elements in Xamarin.Forms:
Button
MenuItem
ToolbarItem
SearchBar
TextCell (and hencealso ImageCell )
ListView
TapGestureRecognizer
With theexception of the SearchBar and ListView element, theseelements definetwo properties:
Command of type System.Windows.Input.ICommand
CommandParameter of type Object
The SearchBar defines SearchCommand and SearchCommandParameter properties, whilethe ListView defines a
RefreshCommand property of type ICommand .
The ICommand interface defines two methods and oneevent:
void Execute(object arg)
bool CanExecute(object arg)
event EventHandler CanExecuteChange

Answer (score 0):

Instead use CollectionView Selection with multiple.
use OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged event in codebehind to delete items

```
      <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
      SelectionMode="Multiple"
      SelectionChanged="OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged">
      ...
          </CollectionView>
           CollectionView collectionView = new CollectionView
          {
             SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple
           };
          collectionView.SetBinding(ItemsView.ItemsSourceProperty, "Monkeys");
          collectionView.SelectionChanged += 
           OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged;


               void OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
               {
                    var previous = e.PreviousSelection;
                    var current = e.CurrentSelection;
                     ...
                }
```